Infinite loop Could not find the '@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server'
I have an angular project that I try to build and start. I use yarn. Node version 20.11.1.
I have an infinite loop saying "Could not find the '@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server'"
when I install it
yarn add @angular-devkit/build-angular@~0.17.0 --dev 
yarn add js-cookie

   "js-cookie": "^3.0.5",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "0.1703.8",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.8",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^17.3.8",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^17.3.8",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^17.3.8",

it turns in cycle, when I install js-cookie, it says can't find @angular-devkit/build-angular, when I install build-angular it says it can't find "js-cookie"...
> yarn start
yarn run v1.22.19
$ ng serve --hmr
Error: Could not find the '@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server' builder's node package.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

ng version
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1703.8 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/build-angular   17.3.8 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core            17.3.8
@angular-devkit/schematics      17.3.8
@angular/cdk                    17.3.10
@angular/cli                    17.3.8 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular             17.3.8
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.4.5
zone.js                         0.14.7

